# How to Prefix Tailwind CSS Classes with Dynamic Brand Names in Next.js

Tags: css, next.js, tailwind-css

I am working on a Next.js project that uses Tailwind CSS for styling. This is not a typical single-site project; instead, it is a branded site where the brand can change. At build time, I supply the brand name as an environment variable, which then influences certain functionalities and the visual aspects of the site.

Here's the challenge I'm facing: Given that I'm using Tailwind CSS, I'm unable to use conventional CSS techniques to apply brand-specific styles (e.g., .BrandA .ProductImage { border-color: red; }).

My idea to solve this is to prefix Tailwind classes with the brand name. For example, for the BrandA, the classes would be something like branda-border-2 or in a shortened form ba-border-2.

I am considering writing a Tailwind plugin to generate these brand-prefixed classes. However, I'm struggling to find a way to access the complete set of Tailwind utilities so that my plugin can extend them all.

Here are my specific questions:

1. Is there a way to dynamically prefix Tailwind CSS classes based on an environment variable (e.g., brand name)?
2. How can I access all Tailwind utilities to ensure that my plugin extends each of them?
3. Are there any best practices or existing solutions for handling brand-specific theming in Tailwind within a Next.js environment?

Any guidance or suggestions on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Surely you don't want to fully duplicate all tailwind classes and utilities albeit prefixed? border-2, border-4 etc shouldn't differ per brand, they should do exactly what they describe.

You could either have a tailwind config file per brand, and separate out the project to work accordingly based off this https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration so that each brand gets its own fonts, colours etc

Or just utilise sass and separate out styling files as well prefix / suffix classes accordingly to brands and what each ones bespoke requirements are.

Comment: The comment above is pretty much spot on. But check out the [theming](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/theme) section inside the official documentation anyway.

Comment: As the different brand may need completely different tailwind classes, I ended up using classNames library to make the code more readable. For basic color/font type of styling, tailwind config does excelent job.